# Selenium WebDriver - How to clear RadEditor content

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, c#

I am working to write some Selenium WebDriver scripts that work with Telerik RadEditor controls. I can successfully enter content into the RadEditor in the following way with C#:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Id_Of_RadEditor_Iframe")).SendKeys("Hello World!");
```

But I have not been able to find a way to clear the existing content of the RadEditor. If I attempt the following:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Id_Of_RadEditor_Iframe")).Clear();
```

I will get this error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state:
Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

Does anyone know a way to clear the existing content from the RadEditor?

P.S. Does anyone think this may be a bug in Selenium WebDriver? Since I know the IFrame is editable since I can successfully perform `SendKeys()`. This seems to make the error incorrect.

Kerry

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167429/what-does-webelement-clear-do-to-textboxes) from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got back around to looking at this issue again as I had more of a need to make this happen. Here is the "work around" I implemented and works for me:

```
var targetElement = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("Id_Of_RadEditor_Iframe"));
int length = targetElement.Text.Length;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    targetElement.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and have yet to find an answer.

As a workaround you can use a loop and:

```
searchBox.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sad that we have to resort to these kind of hacks, but sometimes you have to do what you have to do.